# Horeca profiles: Foursquare API

Tags: android, ios, foursquare

We thought out a concept for a mobile app that allows:

- To create bar/restaurant/event profiles (we want to define them ourselves);
- Access these profiles via Nearby Places (possible to link?);
- Check In, via the profile
- See how many people are checked in into the place, male/female according to the user profile.

> Is this achievable via the Foursquare API?

If not, can it be done in another way? 
I also don't understand very well why I read everywhere that finding or checking in into places via GeoLocation is patented, but at the same time it seems freely available and everyone seems to use it (?).

I would be eternally grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with the foursquare API, but you will only have access to the information of users who check in with your app, and your custom profiles will not appear in Foursquare's venue search results.

With such an app, you will need to take care to maintain user's expectations of privacy. Your app must have a privacy policy that explicitly explains how their information will be used, and what information about them will be made public. See [the Foursquare app policies](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/community) for more information.

Comment: But I can see the placse that are nearby and link my own profile templates to it? Are patents a problem? After all, everyone uses these API's these days.